# User migration in Project Server 2013

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-foundation, project-server

I am working SharePoint. We just migrated all users in MOSS 2007/SharePoint 2010 from one domain to another domain using "*stsadm migrateuser*" script. **Migration completed successfully in MOSS 2007/SharePoint 2010**.
Few of the users are having access to Project Server 2013. Now they cant access the Project Server because the accounts are migrated.
**I want to migrate the accounts in Project Server 2013**. I searched a lot on the web but not found anything.
Please help how can I do the user migration in Project Server 2013.
**Please let me know if you have any query or concern.**
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the article written by Brian Smith which talks about SQL Database edit to update the user account with new domain name:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brismith/2009/06/22/project-server-2007-migration-from-one-domain-to-another/

Answer (score -1):

I have migrated using manual operation in user list.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: I will update but after some time.